# Implementing own Session Management in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session-management

What options are there to implement an own session management in ASP.NET?

I just found one older solution about "highjacking" the built-in session management.

Is there a nice way to implement a component which performs all session tasks?
How can i include a class which receives the HTTP Request and Response during one request process?

Thanks for your help

Regards Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two things,  implement the IHttpSessionState and a HttpModule.  In the HttpModule you hook the applications AcquireRequestState and ReleaseRequestState events.

In the Web.Config you need to remove the default session module and include your own.

The System.We.SessionState namespace has a number of other classes that you can uses in your implementation if you desire and/or you can use for a reference pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article [@ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx).
Please note, that SQL Server and Session State Service providers are built-in in ASP.NET, so if it is enough for you - you can try out one of these...

Comment: As far as i can see, this only aims on implementing an own storage mechanism but not the whole session management. Anyway thanks for the information!